# why probability is multiplied in finding out dependent probabilities?

Tags: probability

Why is probability multiplied in case of dependent events? When we want to find out say, 
We take out a card from a deck of $52$ cards and take another without replacing, We get the probability of getting a Queen in the second draw after we get a Jack in the first is

$\frac{4}{52}$$\times$$\frac{4}{51}$

Why are they multiplied?

Comment: Multiplication principle:  $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B\mid A)$

Comment: I know the formula but why is it multiplied?

Comment: because $Pr(B\mid A)$ is *defined* as $\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$.  In this case, we can intuitively calculate $Pr(B\mid A)$ without needing to calculate $Pr(A\cap B)$ first.  If we wanted to, however, we could calculate $Pr(A\cap B)$ *directly* using counting methods.  Of the $52\cdot 51$ equally likely ways to draw two cards from a deck without replacement in sequence, exactly $4\cdot 4$ of those will have a jack followed by a queen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting a J, in all cases there are 51 cards left of which 4 are Q. Thus the probability of getting a Q after every possible J is always $\frac{4}{51}$. Therefore we can multiply by the probability of getting a J at the first draw.

Comment: why is the probability multiplied?

Comment: Discrete probability is number of solutions divided by number of possibilities. Try computing this directly and tell me what you get. Then observe that the first draw narrows down to $\frac{4}{52}$ of the possibilities, and the second draw further narrows down to $\frac{4}{51}$ of the possibilities.

Comment: That was what I was looking for

Comment: @jyotishrajthoudam: You're welcome. Always remember this concept, as it is extremely useful in discrete probability problems. For example, consider the well-known problem of finding the probability that drawing ten cards from a uniformly shuffled deck gives an Ace as the tenth card. It's easy once you realize that the number of solutions with the Ace as the tenth card is the same as the number of solutions with the Ace as the first card.

Comment: could you also tell how to think of the same process if they are not equally likely events?

Comment: @jyotishrajthoudam: You would have to split cases. If there are two disjoint cases A,B, where A occurs $\frac13$ of the time while B occurs $\frac23$ of the time, then if C occurs $p$ of the time given that A has occurred but $q$ of the time given that $B$ has occurred, then in total C occurs $\frac13 p + \frac23 q$ of the time. You can convince yourself that this is true for discrete probability by counting the solutions divided by possibilities, where you count solutions where A occurs separately from solutions where B occurs.

Comment: Could you lead me to an example solve ?

Comment: @jyotishrajthoudam: Hmm just pretend that you have $3n$ equally likely possibilities, $n$ under A and $2n$ under B, and compute how many possibilities satisfy C. You should get $np+2nq$, and so the probability of C is $\frac{np+2nq}{3n}$. You can try another example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Example.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is probability multiplied in case of dependent events?

Why wouldn't it be?   Look at the factors.

$$\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \mathsf P(A)\times\mathsf P(B\mid A)$$

$\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ is a measure of probability for the union of events $A$ and $B$ (relative to the entire sample space).

$\mathsf P(A)$ is a measure of probability for event $A$ (relative to the entire sample space).

$\mathsf P(B\mid A)$ is a *relative* measure of probability for event $B$ when given that event $A$ occurs.   That is *by definition* the ratio of the measure of the union to the measure of the condition.   $\mathsf P(A\cap B)/\mathsf P(A)$ whenever $\mathsf P(A)\neq 0~$.†

---

PS: † It can be defined in terms of limits when the condition has zero measure, however, that's another topic.